# How to add images in spinner? (array type expected, found int)

Tags: android, image, spinner, custom-adapter

I am trying to add images in my spinner, i am getting some errors in customView

here is my code:

```
s1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.customspinner, R.array.weapicos));


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, int objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.customspinner, parent, false);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
        label.setText(R.array.weapons.[position]);

        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        if ((R.array.weapons[position]).equals("Single Shot")){
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.single_shot);
        }
        else{
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.single_shot);
        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

I am getting errors in labels.setText & in if condition.
Error:(118, 43) error:  expected

Answer (score 0):

Post your crash logs, but anyway :
- a spinner is not a correct way to do what you want (i don't think this can have images)
- why not do a popup and add images in a gallery with checkboxes ?

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You are using Resource array in wrong way. You have to use getResources method to get array from resources.

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weapons);
```

then set data from this array to your labels.

```
label.setText(array[position]);
```